# TypeScript, express, node-dev *and* custom file type loader

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, node-dev

I want to write an node.js server using Express and TypeScript, but I also want to auto-restart (or better yet, hot-reload) it during development as I edit *and* I want to be able to import custom file types.

Webpack can do much of this, but it isn't particularly well-suited for server-side development. node-dev can handle server-restarts but doesn't play particularly nice with TS and custom loaders.

Is there any nice tooling for this particular setup?

Comment: I did eventually get this working with rollup. No need for node-dev, just use rollup plugin `run`. You can write a small plugin to load custom file types

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. You can use nodemon for live reload from your server.

If you need some help doing that I have a lot of projects to show you how to do that.

You can use pure `express` and `nodemon` to achieve what you want.

Comment: How does nodemon handle custom loaders/file types? e.g. I want to load `.sdl` files which requires a small transform first.

Comment: Well never worked with sdl, but there is a lib for handling that. Does that resolver your problem? https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sdl2

Comment: No. I'm talking about GraphQL's SDL, but the specifics aren't important. I want to be able to `import('./foo.sdl')` like I can w/ webpack. Webpack does this via loaders. Other bundlers may offer different solutions; I can write a plugin, that's not a problem, but whatever system needs to support this without me having to load the file with `fs` and transform it at runtime.